# Kohana Validation _external messages

Tags: php, validation, kohana

I have 3 models using validation messages. 2 of them work perfectly for all messages, including _external messages.  The third never returns the custom _external message. The folder structure and way in which I get the errors are identical for each model.

### Folder Structure

`messages\models\verify`

### Catching the Errors

```
catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $e) 
{   
    return $e->errors('models/verify');
}
```

### Errors Passed to View

`array(1) { ["_external"]=> array(1) { ["activation_hash"]=> string(33) "activation hash must not be empty" } }`

### Output External Error

`<?= Arr::path($errors, '_external.activation_hash'); ?>`

### messages\models\verify_external.php

```
return array(
   'activation_hash' => array(
        'not_empty' => 'The email fields did not match'
    ),
);
```

### Validation

```
$extra_rules = Validation::factory($values)
  ->rule('activation_hash', 'not_empty');
$email->check($extra_rules);
```

There that should be everything.  Again, everything is exactly the same amongst 3 models so I assume its a typo or a bug.  Either way I pasted everything here from the code, do you see something I missed? In a debug attempt I put the _external.php file in every directory along the path to the verify folder but got no where so I dont think its my folder structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to include the validation messages in an existing message file.  The purpose of the verify action in my example above was to verify a users email address.  I added the external verify messages to the external email array and it worked as intended.